# Getting values from pro files in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake

I am using Qt 4.5 in Windows XP. My pro file has the variable `VERSION = 1.0`. Now i need to read this variable and get its value (`1.0`) from the source code. So that I don't have to maintain another variable for version inside my source code. I just read from the pro file and update it.  So that the value remains consistent all over my project. Is it possible? Any pointers regarding this are welcome..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use somethings like this:

```
DEFINES += VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
```

This will define a macro that you can use in C source code. Get rid of the backslashes and quotes if you want a number, not a string.

Answer (score 8):

I'll elaborate on this a bit.

In the `YourApp.pro`:

```
VERSION = 0.0.0.1
DEFINES += APP_VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
```

In the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion(QString(APP_VERSION));
```

Wherever else in your sources, e.g. in the imaginary `controller.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
QString yourAppVersion = QCoreApplication::applicationVersion();
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow, when I tried qDebug() << QString(APP_VERSION); in a class.cpp not in main.cpp. has an error "C2065" APP_VERSION: undeclared identifier". but when I tried in main.cpp that worked.